# extracting a particular path from a multi-level dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a matrix:

```
matrix = {
    'A' : {
        'A1' : { 
            'A11' : [1,2,3],
            'A12' : [4,5,6],
        },
        'A2' : {
            'A21' : [11,12,14],
            'A22' : [14,15,16],
        },
        'A3' : {
            'A31' : [111,112,114],
            'A32' : [114,115,116],
        },
    }
}
```

and I want to retrieve particular paths that are dynamically queried -- such `matrix['A']['A2']['A22']` or `matrix['A']['A2']`.

In simpler terms, I have a multi-level dictionary, and a list of strings that map to hierarchies in that dictionary.  such as `['A','A1','A2']`

I'm not sure the most pythonic way of doing this.

The following works.  I'm just wondering if there is a more concise or readable way.  I'd love another set of eyes to offer input and correct an obvious mistake.

```
get_target_path( pth , mtx ):
    try:
        value = mtx    
        for level in pth :
            value = value[level]
        return value
    except KeyError :
        return None

target_path = ['A','A2','A22']
result = get_target_path( target_path , matrix )
```

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with what you already posted. you _could_ create a class that wraps a dict and does this internally so you could call matrix[mystring], but not sure it would be needed.

Answer (score 7):

A shorter option is:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce  # in python 3 only; reduce is a builtin in python 2

def get_target_path(path, matrix):
    try:
        return reduce(operator.getitem, path, matrix)
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

but I don't think it's really any better; I probably would have written it the way you did (though with different spacing :p).

Comment: thanks.  sometimes i just need a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 4):

I like the original fine.  Any answer involving `reduce` is going to leave most code readers scratching their heads in despair (LOL - but there's a reason `reduce` is no longer dignified by being a built-in in Python 3).  I'd just suggest cutting the "wordiness" of it:

```
def get_target_path(pth, mtx):
    for level in pth:
        mtx = mtx.get(level, None)
        if mtx is None:
            break
    return mtx
```

Comment: No need for the None as the second argument in the `dict.get` call. It's None by default :)

Comment: Ya, but "explicit is better than implicit" ;-)